# Prove the following equality

Tags: complex-numbers

So I have the following equality involving complex numbers:
 $$\frac {\sqrt 3 -1}{1-i}(1+\sqrt 3 \,i)(\cos \alpha -i\,\sin\alpha)=2\sqrt {2-\sqrt 3}\left(\cos\left(\frac {7\pi}{12}-\alpha\right)+ \sin\left(\frac {7\pi}{12}-\alpha\right)\right)$$

Guess I have to find that $\alpha$ that is missing, I thought considering both sides of the equation as single complex numbers in the trigonometric form but it seemed only to get more difficult.
I would really appreciate you help and hints, thanks.

Comment: This is hard to read.  Do you mean:   $$\frac {\sqrt 3 -1}{1-i}(1+\sqrt 3 i)(cos \alpha -isin\alpha)=2\sqrt {2-\sqrt 3}\left(cos(\frac {7\pi}{12}-\alpha)+ sin(\frac {7\pi}{12}-\alpha)\right)$$  And, as I think you point out, it is not clear whether you want this to hold for all $\alpha$ or for some.

Comment: I'm, sorry I couldn't write it out much better, you wrote (1+sqrt(3*i) which should have been (1+i*sqrt(3).

Comment: I will edit your question.  If you want to learn about formatting there is a good tutorial [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  Also, you can click on "edit" to see the syntax I used.

Comment: But...shouldn't there be an $i$ on the right hand?  I mean, the left hand is complex and the right hand is real.

Comment: Sorry but there is no 'i' on the right hand. Maybe I should take the real part of the complex number on the left and equalize with the right hand.

Comment: @drin: this *must* be a typo. "Prove the following equality" clearly means that it holds for all $\alpha$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I agree that the title implies it should be true for all $\alpha$, but the "I guess I have to find that $\alpha$ that is missing" plus his specific answer above implies the opposite.

Comment: @drin: ironically, the version without $i$ is an equation with two solutions per period, while the version with is an identity. So we cannot know.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to simplify the rhs. Use the $\cos(A-B),\sin(A-B)$ formulae and the facts that $\cos\frac{7\pi}{12}=\frac{\sqrt3-1}{2\sqrt2},\sin\frac{7\pi}{12}=\frac{\sqrt3+1}{2\sqrt2},\sqrt{2-\sqrt3}=\frac{\sqrt3-1}{\sqrt2}$ to get rhs = $(\sqrt3-1)(\cos\alpha+\sqrt3\sin\alpha)$. Divide both sides by $\sqrt3-1$ and multiply both sides by $1-i$ to get $(1+\sqrt3 i)(\cos\alpha-i\sin\alpha)=(1-i)(\cos\alpha+\sqrt3\sin\alpha)$ and hence $\tan\alpha=\frac{1+\sqrt3}{1-\sqrt3}$, so $\alpha=-\frac{5\pi}{12}$.

Answer (score 0):

This is easier done in the polar form.

This was assuming a typo (missing $i$ in the last term), we have for the modules

$$\frac{\sqrt3-1}{\sqrt2}2\cdot1=2\sqrt{2-\sqrt3}\cdot1,$$ which is true, as $\sqrt2\sqrt{2-\sqrt3}=\sqrt{4-2\sqrt3}=\sqrt{3-2\sqrt3+1}=\sqrt3-1$.

For the arguments,

$$0-(-\frac\pi4)+\frac\pi3-\alpha=0+(\frac7{12}\pi-\alpha),$$
which is also true.

---

Otherwise, the argument equation becomes

$$0-(-\frac\pi4)+\frac\pi3-\alpha=0+k\pi,$$ and $$\alpha=\frac{7\pi}{12}+k\pi.$$

Then the modules equation is also verified, as the last factor is $1$! ($k\pi$ comes form the fact that the last factor can also be negative.)